# How to display a component in another component dynmically Angular2

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to display a component in another component dynamically but have no idea to do it dynamically .. like I have some records(rows) and on click of particular record I need to replace that record with that component and perform some actions over that particular record.

Would anyone please provide me any approach how to do so.

component.html:

```
<table>
        <tr *ngFor = "let log of logs">
            <td  *ngIf = "log.selectedLogs.length > 0>
                <div class="card">
                    <div *ngIf = "log.selectedLogs.length > 0">
                        <div class="detail">
                            <table class="table-responsive">
                                <tr *ngFor = "let sl of log.selectedLogs" (click) = "editLog('selectedLogs', sl)">
                                    <td>{{sl.field1}}</td>
                                    <td>{{sl.field2}}</td>
                                    <td>{{sl.field3}}</td>
                                    <td>{{sl.field4 | number: '1.2-2'}}</td>
                                    <td class="text-right">${{sl.field5}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5">
                                        <edit-logs *ngIf="edit"></edit-logs>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="total">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="text-right">Total:</td>
                                    <td>{{totalHrs}}</td>
                                    <td class="text-right">${{totalAmount}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here I am trying to open `edit-logs` component when any `sl` is selected. I need to display that component with the previous values and need to update logs..

Need help.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I didn't get it.. would you please provide me any example

Comment: What i am trying to do is I have some dynamic cards let 5 and In those cards I am displaying multiple records using *ngfor ... what I want is when I click on a row of those records ... I need to display an edit form (new component) at the same place of selected row .. Where I need to display old information and need to update it...

Comment: The list in every card is of different type

Comment: @warrior how about having disabled input text boxes and enabling those on click of edit and disabling again on save/cancel click?

Comment: @localStanger I have added a scenario please look into it and let me know if need any other help

Comment: @JiteshYadav I am  using another component to display coz I have a complete form to edit ... and I need to use it at many places

Comment: @warrior in that case see if bootstrap modal suits your need. You can pass the data from the row you have clicked before opening the modal. Please check https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples. Or have separate component hidden initially and on click of edit show it and pass the row data in @Input() variable.

Comment: @JiteshYadav I dont need to show a modal .. need to just select the row and replace that row with new component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching more about this I found accordion which perfectly suits to my case. Simple accordion control for your angular2 applications using bootstrap3. If you don't want to use it without bootstrap - simply create proper css classes.